# Most efficient method for quintic real root isolation?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have a quintic polynomial whose real roots I would like to isolate. Having seen so many methods on the internet tailored towards different applications, I'm unsure exactly which direction to take.

Options I've seen have been:

- Sturm sequences
- Sturm sequences combined with the continued-fraction method
- Vincent-Collins-Akritas method
- Isolator polynomials (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.133.2233&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- Newton interval method

etc. etc.

Which algorithm should I employ to solve my equation with the most efficiency and robustness?

Edit:

Of course, it is often difficult to measure "efficiency" without benchmarks etc. but I am mostly talking about generally-accepted computational superiority i.e. I have often seen that it is rather obvious when certain algorithms are prefered to others, but due to my lack of experience I cannot determine this for myself.

Comment: How do you measure efficiency and robustness?

Comment: @lhf fair question, I've added and edit explaining mostly what I mean

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Making a rough sketch, three range intervals to find number of real roots labelled :

1. 5 roots /inner
2. 3 roots/ peripheral
3. 1 root / outermost

to decide how many real roots have to be iterated.

Several schemes like Newton-Raphson can be employed.

[image]